# Hardware Accelerated WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, hardware-acceleration

Is there a way to get the WebBrowser control to use hardware acceleration?  I've got it running in IE9 standards mode in my app, but it is still really slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the instruction in IE SDK [FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (MSDN documentation).

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the point of duplicating MSDN documentation. Information may be updated/revised on MSDN and render the information here out of date. I would not expect a click to be too much hussle.

Comment: The general preference on [so] is for users to not need to click a link in order to see such trivial information. Instead, summarize.

Comment: Having to exclude out of date and sometimes incorrect MFC documentation when searching for up-to-date SDK documentation even when doing research for MFC project, I would say duplicating documentation do more harm than good in the long run.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for.  I found the reg key to make my app run in IE9 standards mode, but I didn't have the gpu rendering key in my registry so it wasn't immediately apparent to me.  I just added the key and it all works now.

Comment: Any idea if this can be done programatically, or if it has to be done with the registry?

Comment: It is usually done at install time. MSI authoring tools like Visual Studio setup project or InstallShield support importing reg files or creating key/values in an interface similar to regedit.

Comment: I ended up just programatically adding the registry key.  For those who do this make sure that on your dev box you also put in an entry for appname.vshost.exe.  Otherwise when you debug it won't work.  Took me a hour of banging my head against a wall to discover my oversight.

Comment: Process Monitor is a good tool to discover where your webbrowser is reading settings.